# php - issue with booleans in if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

I have been running into a weird issue for some time with php now and wonder if anybody can help. It's probably a totally minor stupid thing I don't see.

"if" statements don't seem to work for me when I use && and || for logical expressions.
Latest example:

```
$isNotSet = !isset($moved); // var_dump prints false
$moveSuccess = $moved instanceof SuccessNotification; // var_dump prints true
if(($isNotSet == true) || ($moveSuccess == true)){
```

the script always breaks at exactly that line and doesn't go any further. It won't execute anything after this.
I have tried lots of things, e.g.

```
if(!isset($moved) || $moved instanceof SuccessNotification){
```

or

```
if(!isset($moved) === true || $moved instanceof SuccessNotification){
```

or

```
$isNotSet = !isset($moved);
$moveSuccess = $moved instanceof SuccessNotification;
if($isNotSet === true || $moveSuccess === true){
```

All don't work. I'm aware they all mean the same, I was just trying to eliminate the thought of being on the wrong track. Some of those examples are marked as syntax error in Netbeans, but not all of them, which got me thinking.

I'd like to know what's going on here because this limits coding a lot. But as I said, I probably overlook a totally simple thing.

edit: the script breaks without any errors or warnings shown, it just stops working at that line

edit2:
I took the snippet and executed it on its own.

```
$moved = new SuccessNotification($code, $title, $message);
echo 1;
$isNotSet = !isset($moved);
echo 2;
$moveSuccess = $moved instanceof SuccessNotification;
echo 3;
if(($isNotSet === true) || ($moveSuccess === true) || 1){
    echo 4;    
}else{
    echo 5;    
}
echo 6;
```

This prints "123", nothing else. And yes, I have included the SuccessNotification class (otherwise there would have been an error anyways) which is being used system-wide already and properly working, just removed that line for posting here.
I take it that nobody really has a clue and therefore tries to find a simple solution which is ok because I thought it's just a simple thing. But I realize I have tried everything you suggest or would do in this situation.

Comment: Have you tried printing value of $moveSuccess and $isNotSet before the comparison?

Comment: yes, it says in the code/comments ;)

Comment: Add `|| 1` in your condition & check if it now goes into the if statement.

Comment: How about enclosing each in brackets... if(!isset($moved) || ($moved instanceof SuccessNotification))

Comment: What does "it doesn't go any further" mean exactly? The program exits at that point? Have you checked for error messages, maybe in the logs? If that's not what it means, what does it do exactly and what would you expect it to do instead?

Comment: I have used brackets in some cases because it made the syntax error markings go away but it didn't help the code.

Comment: "it doesn't go any further" means the script exits there. Errors aren't shown at all (see "edit"). When I echo stuff before the if, inside the if, inside the else, and after the whole if-else, it only shows what has been echoed before the line containing the if statement.

Comment: I think it should be `if(!isset($moved) === false || $moved instanceof SuccessNotification){`

Comment: It cannot be a syntax error, else the whole thing wouldn't run at all. `if` statements don't simply "break", no matter what the condition. The problem is likely in some other piece of code you're not showing.

Comment: I agree with @deceze. You can also confirm by printing something before the condition and after the condition. To see if it even reach that condition.

Comment: @rccoros you guys should read everything before posting as I tried exactly that ;) I will now try running the snippet on its own and see what's happening. I don't see why the problem should be in some other piece of code when it breaks exactly there but ok, check the edit I'm going to post

Comment: I guess we need more code.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://3v4l.org/iIkT5

Answer (score -1):

Shouldnt it be:

```
if(($isNotSet === true) || ($moveSuccess === true)){
```

Instead of:

```
if(($isNotSet == true) || ($moveSuccess == true)){
```

Comment: to be entirely correct with the type, yes. I have tried both, with and without additional brackets.